# redirection fails when called after deleting application cookies from the browser says cors error

Tags: django, python-3.x, session, django-rest-framework, http-redirect

In my django application, HttpResponseRedirection failing
When i do it for the first time it passes and redirects.

```
if request.user.is_anonymous:
    request.session.flush()
    print(request.get_host())
    sso_auth_url = 'https://' + request.get_host().split(',')[0] + reverse('dcmsisso:auth')
    windows_auth_url = os.path.join(API_BASE_URL, 'api', API_VERSION, 'windows/auth')
    redirect_url = windows_auth_url + '?redirecturl=' + sso_auth_url + '?next=' + next_url
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

when i am in some page, and delete all the session cookies, there try to reload the page it enters this block and does not call the next function.
But if i left click on the failed url and open it in new page, then it redirects to the home page. 
I have been trying to resolve this error from 3 days. can any one suggest.
I can give more info, i dont know what is missing.

Editing: I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://iamws-xxx.com/api/v1/windows/auth?redirecturl=https://dcms.yyy.com/dcmsisso/auth?next=/home' (redirected from 'https://dcms.yyy.com/getUser') from origin 'https://dcms.yyy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In my settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
"https://iamws.xxx.com",
"https://dcms.yyy.com"
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
'iamws-xxx.com',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS=True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
'accept',
'accept-encoding',
'authorization',
'content-type',
'dnt',
'origin',
'user-agent',
'x-csrftoken',
'x-requested-with',
'content-type',
'Pragma',
'Expires',
'Cache-Control',
]
```

and i also have added cors-headers in installed application and made changes in middleware too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming here, you've moved on from your redirection issue and
>   you're debugging the cors error while accessing your API - in that
>   case, you'd probably want to update the question title.

For future readers - before debugging any cors related issue make sure you have the imports in your `settings.py` file configured in the correct order.

#### `CorsMiddleware` should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s `CommonMiddleware` or Whitenoise’s `WhiteNoiseMiddleware`. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses. -

As quoted in [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

---

### Initiate investigation

Use your browser's Developer tools, to investigate the networks tab.

*Not really sure, if the error text shared by you is from a terminal, logs or networks tab.*

Select the failed request in your Network's tab and examine the Headers, Preview, and Response for the request.

It should help you to understand which cors header is actually being requested and whether you've included the same in your `settings.py` under `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [...]`

---

### Encountering CORS policy block after redirection!

I could only understand a part of your redirection logic but it seems like you are using IAM for some sort of LDAP authentication or OAuth. In any case, you might wanna make sure you're working within the allowed and appropriately assigned CORS policy from the connected systems.

---

All the best!

Comment: hi, Thank you so much for the response. i did the changes suggested by you. and editing the post. This is sort of LDAP authentication, i passes through when you do it for the first time from a particular api, but it fails when called from another api.

Comment: The erros are copied from browsers console

Comment: If the other application is not in production, then you can update its `settings.py` files to allow all domains in `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` or simply setting `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True` . This will help you to verify if indeed this is a multiple origin issue. If you can establish this fact, then you can accordingly set the security for your cors origin.